# Why am I getting the previous saved value from FileUtilsDisplayTime() in flutter?

Tags: file, flutter, dart

I want to read my time and pass to my toast function.But I am getting the previously stored number and not the present value.

Here is the code:

```
String time = '2';

String getTimeForDisplay() {
  FileUtilsDisplayTime().readFromFile().then((String value) {
    time = value;
    print("time from file---" + time);
  });
  return time;
}

void notificationToast() {
  String s = getTimeForDisplay();
  int timeIn = int.parse(s);
  print("time incoming---------" + s);
  Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: "------------------------------------------------message---------",
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
      timeInSecForIos: timeIn,
      gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      textColor: Colors.red,
      fontSize: 16.0);
}
```

time incoming and time from file are not the same values?

Comment: No,it is not about the current system time or anything.It is the time for which the toast has to be displayed.If you habe missed the last line,please do mind reading it again

Comment: Sorry my mistake, Yes your previous question and this one are related. You are creating Settings for customizing the `Toast` messages. I had misread the question initially.

Comment: Ok.............i fixed this but can u help me in running the toast for a specified duration of time?

Comment: It might not be possible for [fluttertoast package](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast), I tried to find properties to customise duration in their documentation. Options i could find for customizing toast duration were the `toastLength` property which has only two values. `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` and `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT`. The other duration property `timeInSecForIosWeb` is mentioned as only for IOS.

Comment: There is another option but it will require major re-writing of the code, using Flutter's `SnackBar` widget [SnackBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SnackBar-class.html).